# Bootstrap doesn't along well with Sass

Tags: html, css, sass

In this case Sass is working normally.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

</head>
<body>

<h1>This is a title</h1>

</body>
</html>


Sass Project.

 $primary-color:red;

h1{
  color:$primary-color;
}
```

But when I put a link from bootstrap or ionicons , Sass stops working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>

<h1>This is a title</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not sure what exactly you're asking. Can you clarify the issue with what you have narrowed down?

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

when I put this link for using bootstrap now Sass is not working.

Comment: Do you add this before your stylesheet entry? Have you tried other stylesheets?

Comment: <link href="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@4.2.6/dist/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

Yep ionicons don't work too

Comment: Like if I add a new link , Sass is not longer working.

Comment: None of the links you posted seem to return CSS when navigating directly in the browser.

Comment: I got it from here : https://getbootstrap.com/ , you are gonna found it down bellow.

Comment: Can you please edit your post with what doesn't work?

Comment: You can check the edit.

Comment: Also, you're not clear on "stops working". What do you see that leads you to believe that? Also, you should be putting your `style.css` **after** the Bootstrap CSS.

Comment: Oh that was the problem I put the  Boostrap link before and now is working. Ty I guess. :)

Answer (score 0):

As explained by Sunny Patel in a comment, you should be putting your `bootstrap.min.css` **before** other CSS:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
```